# Toggling/Sliding in Two Navbars

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a navigation bar that when clicking on the menu icon will slide in the "#secondary-nav" and hide the "#primary-nav". The jquery however does not seem to be showing the "#secondary-menu". Provided below is the HTMl, CSS, and jQuery.

Example here - http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/6lM53. 

My jQuery is not that good, so any help will be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Michael Charles Criste</a> -->
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul id="primary-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a></li>
      </ul>
       <ul id="secondary-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul> 

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#primary-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
#secondary-menu{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $('#primary-menu').show();
    $('#secondary-menu').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue for you:

There seems to be an issue with your CSS. Instead of using the "visibility: Hidden" use the "display: none"

```
    #primary-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

#secondary-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Also I changed the JS by changing the collapse to toggle.

```
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#secondary-menu" ).toggle();
   $( "#primary-menu" ).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great fix but why does the primary-nav seem to be showing a horizontal scrollbar before disappearing?

Comment: Do you have an example of what it is you are trying to accomplish? Would you be interested in just creating a whole new nav bar rather than using bootstraps version?

Comment: yes codyhouse does this secondary sliding navigation well. http://codyhouse.co/demo/secondary-sliding-navigation/index.html